# gdalwarp '-tps' equilvalent in C# wrapper?

Tags: c#, gdalwarp, osgeo

I am attempting to do the following from code:

```
gdal_translate.exe --config GDAL_DATA "D:\gdal\bin\gdal-data" -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 0 0 -108.724530873811 40.1376029956585 ..<truncated>.. -gcp 1920 1080 -108.700701203799 40.0986057211287 z.png y.tif

gdalwarp.exe --config GDAL_DATA "D:\gdal\bin\gdal-data" -of GTiff -wo "SAMPLE_GRID=YES" -wo "SAMPLE_STEPS=100" -overwrite -tps -r cubic -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata "0 0 0" -dstnodata "0 0 0" y.tif y_done.tif
```

Starting with a non-georeference png file (obtained from a camera mounted on an aircraft), I add externally calculated GCPs to create a GeoTIFF.  Using that GeoTIFF, I want to warp that image to display it on a 2d map.

Using the -tps option in the gdalwarp command has so-far provided the best alignment for the resulting image.

In C# code, I am struggling to achieve the same final result using AutoCreateWarpedVRT:

```
Dataset dswarp = Gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(dsTiff, s_srs_wkt, t_srs_wkt, ResampleAlg.GRA_CubicSpline, 0.125);
ds_out = dvTiff.CreateCopy(path + ".wrp.tif", dswarp, 0, null, null, "");
```

This creates a warped GeoTIFF but appears similar to an -order 2 (per the VRT file) polynomial rather than tps.

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only answer I found was to dive into C/C++ instead of the C# wrapper.  There just wasn't enough exposed functionality for me to using the C# wrapper.